# What is the billing for an aws s3 sync operation which makes no changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an aws s3 bucket with 10,000 files totally around 1GB in size.

I call:

```
aws s3 sync <remote bucket> <local folder> --exact-timestamps
```

And no files are found to be changed, so no actual file downloads take place.

However, there must be data exchange for the sync - does anyone know how much?

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Also, please have a look at the explicit description of the tag you've used: "QUESTIONS MUST BE ABOUT PROGRAMMING. Questions about general S3 support, functionality, configuration, etc. are OFF-TOPIC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListObjects()` API call returns a maximum of 1000 objects.

Therefore, the AWS CLI would require at least 10 API calls to retrieve information about 10,000 objects to determine whether files need to by sync'd.

However, since the cost of requests is only `$0.005 per 1,000 requests`, the cost would be quite small.